# Simple way to catch misspelled Python object attributes?

Tags: python, ipython, interactive

When I test/debug my Python code interactively, I'm often sidetracked by accidental mis-spellings - they make me think something is wrong with my code when there isn't.

For example, my object `c` has a setter for the `subframe` property:

```
c.suframe = (0,0,256,256); i = c.snap(verbose=False); print(c._last_transfer_duration); show(i*10)
```

I expected to get a 256x256 subframe, but because I spelled it `suframe` instead of `subframe`, I'd just created an attribute `suframe` and there was (unexpectedly) no effect on subframing. This was an interactive typo, not a code bug. But I had to *notice* the misspelling to figure that out.

Is there a simple way to get Python to complain so I *notice* that the misspelling, instead of silently accepting the new attribute?

(Lint won't help - this is interactive debugging, not code in a file.)

[FWIW, I'm using iPython.]

Comment: Use tab-complete? Otherwise, what you wrote *is* valid Python and the interpreter would have a hard time guessing that you didn't want to create a new attribute named `suframe`. 
Perhaps you could use `__slots__` to limit which attributes can be set on the object?

Comment: You can use `__slots__` for this

Comment: In my case I have lots of configuration objects that serve somewhat the same purpose as Meta classes you see on Django Model or Admin classes.  It’s very easy to misspell attributes.   Anyway, rather than slots I’ve had good success making them into Pydantic classes.